# Horizontal RecyclerView with nested HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Im trying to rig a horizontally oriented RecyclerView with child items that contain a HorizontalScrollView. What I have configured right now is not allowing the nested HorizontalScrollView to scroll its content.

Heres an abbreviated version of my activity layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/home_recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here's an abbreviated version of the item layout:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
       android:id="@+id/main_card"
       android:layout_width="335dp"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">

      <HorizontalScrollView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"">

         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

      </HorizontalScrollView>

   </android.support.v7.widget.CardView
```

So Im trying to get the Text content inside the Horizontal ScrollView to be scrollable.

EDIT :

Below is a screenshot of the textview that will not scroll. As you can see, the text is cut off at the end of the view, and this is why Im looking to implement horizontal scrolling.

[image]

NOTE: I tried changing the LayoutManager associated with my RecyclerView to have vertical orientation, and horizontal scrolling works as expected. Knowing this, it seems that the RecyclerView is absorbing all scroll events and not allowing the nested HorizontalScrollView to do its thing

Comment: Is some path of the text of the TextView being cut-off? Please a screenshot will be helpful.

Comment: @Ozuf - The text runs to the end of its parent view and gets cut off. Im trying to put the text in a horizontal scroll so that text that is longer than the parent can be scrolled horizontally to show more content

Comment: Please can you show the screenshot?

Comment: @Ozuf Added the screenshot along with update

Comment: Try adding `android:scrollHorizontally="true"` to the TextView. If it doesn't work, unwrap the TextView from the HorizontalScrollView and try it again. Please let me know the result.

Comment: @Ozuf that did not work

Comment: Ok try this. Wrap the recyclerview in nestedscrollview and try it again.

Comment: @Ozuf Still nothing :/

Comment: Hey @raisedandglazed, were you able to implement this in the end? Having the same problem here to put a HorizontalScrollView inside a Horizontal RecyclerView.